# Is this necrotizing skin infection caused by Staphylococcus aureus?

Tags: microbiology, homework

A 5-year-old boy returns from summer camp with several minor cuts and abrasions on legs. He has fever
and extensive cellulitis, subcutaneous tissue and muscles are involved. Necrotic tissues were surgically
reomoved and broad spectrum antibiotics were used. Which of the following microorganisms usually
causes necrotizing fasciitis?

- a. bacillus cereus
- b. clostridium tetani
- c. A-group streptococci
- d. Micrococcus sp.
- e. Staphylococcus aureus

It is so severe that I started think that Staphylococcus aureus is possible.
My previous answer was A-group streptococci, but I disagree with it now.

**What is causing the case?**

Comment: if broad spectrum are being given chances are that it will be staph aureus because nowadays resistance to multiple antibiotics is being found in it.

Comment: @biogirl broad spectrum antibiotics are the standard first step in treating just about any infection.

Comment: @terdon You are right.I just thought that  because the question specifically states "broad spectrum" it may hint at staph aureus.I may be wrong.

Comment: At the moment, I am not sure what is the right answer. I am wondering still between C and E.

Comment: It is not mentioned in the question about the time period, how long it took that the surgeon was done from  the incident. If it was done very fast after incident, then I would pick Staphylococcus aureus. However, I do not understand its pathology yet.

Comment: I still cannot find any reason for C, since it is not pneumonic. The fever is only related to the symptoms of necrosis. Staph aureus is related with post-operative wounds which may imply that also minor cuts and abrasions can cause it. So most support goes for Staph aureus at the moment.

Comment: Murray says that the answer is C for cellutitis and necrotizing fasciitis in a table, but I have found no explanation. I want to understand why.

Comment: @Masi Have you read the article on Necrotizing fasciitis on wikipedia ?

Comment: Yes, but my books cover the topic much better and deeper. They say that the answer is C by empirical evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staphylococcal infection is more likely to cause abscesses and Streptococcal infection is more likely to cause cellulitis. It is not clear how a 5 year old did not get medical attantion till he got to this serious state. Why was culture not done? Surgical removal of necrotic tissue due to cut and bruises? doesn't tally with cellulitis. Incision and drainage is a standard proceedure for absecesses, is that what was done? Is this a hypothetical question?

Comment: I do not know. I hope it is.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is caused by A-group streptococci. Source Murray and empirical evidence.